# Xamarin: Modal from not popping

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

since a couple of weeks I have the problem that a modal form which provides a spinner and a label is not popping anymore. It was running in older versions but not with all NuGet Packages updated.
Any idea what this can be?
Funnywise it is working on some forms and not on others.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
       
        try
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BusyPopUpPage("loading products"));
            
            //ActivityTracker.StartSpinner(true);
            base.OnAppearing();
            IsFiltered = false;
            LblAttributesVisible = false;
            AllProducts = await App.AllProductsController.GetAllProducts();

            grouped = new ObservableCollection<AssortmentGroups>();

            GroupProducts();
            AllProductsListView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
            AllProductsListView.ItemsSource = grouped;
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await CreateNewBug.CreateANewBug(ex.Message,"Error in Module " + ex.Source,"\nMessage---\n{ 0}" + ex.Message + "\nInnerException---\n{ 0}" + ex.InnerException + "\nStackTrace---\n{ 0}" + ex.StackTrace + "\nTargetSite---\n{ 0}" + ex.TargetSite);
            ToastOptions toastOptions = Message.ShowMessage("An error was raised and a new bug created in our system.", "error");
            await this.DisplayToastAsync(toastOptions);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: try 2 things: 1 - let your `OnAppearing` method synchronous, that is, remove all `async/await`. 2 - remove your popModalAsync of your try, open a finally and put in there and test. If hasn't any error (null, cast, etc) in your methods that you call in your `OnAppearing`, then it could be so faster that has no animation to push the popup and then pop it. If you want to try too: After your spinner, put: `await Task.Delay(500);` and test it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both solutions but with the same result. The modal is not popping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong because your r struck in an infinite loop, since await Navigation.PopModalAsync(); recall the OnAppearing of a page u poped too.

I recommend another solution for your loading page. Instead of pushing and popModel create overlapping pages. Then show and hide them whenever you want.
example:

```
 <Grid>
            
            <!--here you can add what u want to display on your page-->
            
            
        <Grid x:Name="LoadingGrid" BackgroundColor="White" IsVisible="false" >
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
               
                <ActivityIndicator HeightRequest="50"  Color="#2196F3" IsRunning="True" />
               
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

in you code behind

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
       
        try
        {
           this.LoadingGrid.IsVisible = true;
            
            //ActivityTracker.StartSpinner(true);
            base.OnAppearing();
            IsFiltered = false;
            LblAttributesVisible = false;
            AllProducts = await App.AllProductsController.GetAllProducts();

            grouped = new ObservableCollection<AssortmentGroups>();

            GroupProducts();
            AllProductsListView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
            AllProductsListView.ItemsSource = grouped;
            
            this.LoadingGrid.IsVisible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await CreateNewBug.CreateANewBug(ex.Message,"Error in Module " + ex.Source,"\nMessage---\n{ 0}" + ex.Message + "\nInnerException---\n{ 0}" + ex.InnerException + "\nStackTrace---\n{ 0}" + ex.StackTrace + "\nTargetSite---\n{ 0}" + ex.TargetSite);
            ToastOptions toastOptions = Message.ShowMessage("An error was raised and a new bug created in our system.", "error");
            await this.DisplayToastAsync(toastOptions);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: This could be a solution but the app we are developing has tons on pages and we need a centralized point which we can easily launch for the loading spinner. If we add this grid to each page it would be a problem to maintain. A possibility could be to add this to a control template. But something I have to investigate. But it seems not to solve the issue we have. If the code is running over the PopModalAsync it should execute but it does not.

Comment: can you please accept my answer since it solved ur issue

Comment: I can't as you just commented it. Can you put it into an answer? Then I can mark it as solution

Comment: i edited my solution please accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Amjad Saab solved the problem!
I don't know but it seems this was different in older versions of Xamarin Forms.
The problem is as Amjad said: If I PopModalAsync within onAppearing it restarts the override of OnAppearing and end in a loop.
I changed my code to the following:`

```
public AllProductsListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadData();
    }
    protected async void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BusyPopUpPage("loading products"));
            base.OnAppearing();
            IsFiltered = false;
            LblAttributesVisible = false;
            AllProducts = await App.AllProductsController.GetAllProducts();
            grouped = new ObservableCollection<AssortmentGroups>();
            GroupProducts();
            AllProductsListView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
            AllProductsListView.ItemsSource = grouped;
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
        
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await CreateNewBug.CreateANewBug(ex.Message,"Error in Module " + ex.Source,"\nMessage---\n{ 0}" + ex.Message + "\nInnerException---\n{ 0}" + ex.InnerException + "\nStackTrace---\n{ 0}" + ex.StackTrace + "\nTargetSite---\n{ 0}" + ex.TargetSite);
            ToastOptions toastOptions = Message.ShowMessage("An error was raised and a new bug created in our system.", "error");
            await this.DisplayToastAsync(toastOptions);
        }
    }
```

So what I did was:

1. I changed the name of my "override OnAppearing" function to LoadData(). So there is no OnAppearing function anymore
2. Run the LoadData() function from the page directly after InitializeComponent()

`

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange. I reduce my code to the following:

```
 await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BusyPopUpPage("loading products"));
            LoopCounter++;
            //base.OnAppearing();
            //IsFiltered = false;
            //LblAttributesVisible = false;
            //AllProducts = await App.AllProductsController.GetAllProducts();

            //grouped = new ObservableCollection<AssortmentGroups>();

            //GroupProducts();
            //AllProductsListView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
            //AllProductsListView.ItemsSource = grouped;
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            await DisplayAlert("Info", "LoopCounter=" + LoopCounter, "OK");
```

So, we just have the PushModalAsync and the PopModalAsync. All other code not running currently. I added a loop-counter because I see that the code is running 2 times. If I run the code with the PopModalAsync it runs 2 times through the whole code. If I remove the PopModalAsync it only runs 1 time through the code. Maybe this is the problem.
I will also continue testing

Comment: your logic is wrong because your r struck in an infinite loop, since await Navigation.PopModalAsync(); recall the OnAppearing of a page u poped too